# Image classification with Keras on Tensorflow: how to find which images are misclassified during training?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, tensorboard, ubuntu-17.04

I use Keras 2.0 (TensorFlow backend) on Ubuntu 17.04 to do binary image classification. Everything works great except I'd like to see which images are misclassified. How do I do that?

Also, unsure if it'd answer my problem, but in TensorBoard I can't get the `image` tab to work, so don't know if that'd help.

I've done a lot of googling, of course, but I just can't find an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply predict the classifications and compare with your true values...

```
predicted = model.predict(trainingImages)
```

Subtracting and removing the sign should result in near zero results for the right ones and high results for the wrong ones:

```
result = numpy.absolute(trainingClasses-predicted)
```

Comment: thank you, of course! Amazing how it's always obvious once explained ...

Comment: @Daniel Möller  What is trainingClasses here ?  or 
Is it a list or something else ?

Comment: It's `y_train` as they usually name it. Your true labels, true target data, true results, etc.

Comment: and how can we, from this, get information about a single value? `result` in this case is an array of an array of numbers...

Comment: @Aristides, get slices or elements from the array as you would normally: `sample0 = result[0]`, `sample1 = result[1]`.

Comment: @DanielMöller right so then I have to iterate over every single element, and check which ones have any result-of-subtraction above a certain threshold right? Is there any way to en-masse get all of the elements that were predicted incorrectly, and the information associated? For example, if we're doing image classification, how can I get the filepath of a single image or something along those lines?

Comment: @DanielMöller I think your second comment here is very important and should be included into the answer of the question, to be more visible for other users